# Map Reduce. DUDA

Tags: dictionary, average, reduce

The calculation of averages in map-reduce is an example of a function that supports composition, that is, it is possible to combine the average of two subsets. Is it True or false?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the calculation of averages in map-reduce is an example of a function that does not support composition. It is not possible to combine the average of two subsets: Let's suppose that we want to calculate the ordered average quantity for a given product. An important property of averages is that they do not admit composition. Instead of combining the average of two subsets, I need to take the total amount of each subset, combine them, and then calculate the mean for the combined sum.